# automap different dll to different databases

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate, connection-string

I recently started building a domain at home using nhibernate 3 and fluent nhibernate as my ORM.  Everything in my domain works.

I am currently wanting to explore the possibility of using automapper to map different dlls in my solution to different databases.  My google-kung-fu is finding little and non-related results with my "research".

Can it be done?  If it were to be done, what would happen to my IQueryables where my query can contain entities that come from different databases that are not necessarily hosted by the same database instance or physical machine?

for example, I am wanting to do (the connection strings are different):

connectionstring1: Data Source=myTestServerAddress;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=myTestUsername;Password=myTestPassword;

```
namespace test //in assembly test, connectionstring1
{
    public class test
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string testme { get; set; }
    }
}
```

connectionstring2: Data Source=myTestTestServerAddress;Initial Catalog=TestTest;User Id=myTestTestUsername;Password=myTestTestPassword;

```
namespace testtest //in assembly testtest, connectionstring2
{
    public class testtest
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual test test { get; set; } //test is in different assembly
    }
}
```

Comment: You can automap the two different assemblies to different databases.  This would just be two different session factories (one for each different database).  As far as the querying is concerned I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want them to reside in different databases. You can use sharding to loadbalance or (like Cole W said) save only the test_id in testtest use 2 different sessionfactories and open a session from the first to get test when needed.